# log4cplus cannot find AppenderFactory

Tags: c++, dll, log4cplus

I regularly use log4cplus, but I have encountered a new problem.

I have a windows application which uses a dll (LoadLibrary)

They are built on different compilers, but use dlls with the same name (including log4cplus.dll) also built on different compilers. The app and all the dlls it uses are built in one environment (vs2008). The dll and all the dlls it uses are built on another environment (vs2013).

LoadLibrary failed until I changed the application to pass the LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH flag to LoadLibraryEx, which appears to allow the dll to load its own dependencies successfully, except now I get these runtime errors

```
log4cplus:ERROR PropertyConfigurator::configureAppenders()- Cannot find AppenderFactory: log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus:ERROR PropertyConfigurator::configureAppenders()- Cannot find AppenderFactory: log4cplus::ConsoleAppender
log4cplus:ERROR PropertyConfigurator::configureLogger()- Invalid appender: ROLLING
```

Logging works for all applications built in either environment. 
Logging also works for this app and dll both built in the same environment.
I changed the dll to statically link log4cplusS.lib, but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

First off, use the same compiler for everything. It is basically impossible to make things work when using different compiler versions. Once you are compiling everything with the same compiler, try to solve other problems, if any still remain.

Comment: I mentioned there is no problem when built on the same compiler, but dll's usually don't have this requirement. The reason why mixing would be beneficial is incremental upgrades to the newest environment.